# Generate dataset for Binary Classification in k-NN using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, dataset, normal-distribution

I want to generate random dataset which have 2 labels `0` and `1`. This is my distribution :

```
p(x|y = 0) = N(x1;µ1,σ2 1)N(x2;µ2,σ2 2) 
p(x|y = 1) = N(x1;µ3,σ2 3)N(x2;µ4,σ2 4)
```

where x=(x1,x2)T contains the two continuous valued attributes.

How to solve it using python? What library should I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities, probably the simpliest is to just use `numpy` [random number generator](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html), thus

```
import numpy as np
N = 100

mean1, mean2, std1, std2 = 1, 5, 2, 3
x0 = np.random.normal(loc=[mean1, mean2], scale=[std1, std2], size=(N, 2))

mean3, mean4, std3, std4 = 2, -2, 1, 0.1
x1 = np.random.normal(loc=[mean3, mean4], scale=[std3, std4], size=(N, 2))
```